# Protecting VS2015 Solution at Customer

Tags: c#, c++, object, compilation, visual-studio-2015

I'm in a situation where I'm required to put my development environment (VS2015 and Solution) at a Client's location. 
I'm wondering if there may be, perhaps, a better way than to have all the sources there.

My Solution is comprised of multiple Projects, the main part of which constitute a non changing Engine. Is there a way, then, that I can have those Projects (which should never change) as OBJ files (for example) or other files which aren't just flat text files containing all the sources?
While other projects (two or three of them) would remain Source based (cause I'm more at ease showing those sources to the client)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to do that ? I mean from a technical perspective. (Dev environment @ Client)

Comment: @Acemad, it's not technical. It's just for specific military industries. So, no offsite development.

Comment: @Cypher_CS: "No offsite development" means "no offsite sources". If you don't have onsite sources either, then _where are the sources?!_

Comment: No. The code is proprietary ours. However, I don't want it to just lie there. They do go over the code with stuff like checkmarx. But otherwise, I bring in my own code into an air-gapped lab, more or less.

Answer (score 4):

Compile your sensitive sources into .lib files, and link those into your project. You could also make .DLLs but that would be more effort.

You may have to make multiple copies of your .lib files if you have multiple project configurations (e.g., 32 bit, 64 bit).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project an add the solutions you want so distibute to it.

Compile all other parts you do not want to give away in source and add the compiled dlls as references (Right click on a project and click the "Browse" button in the Add Reference dialog).

Be sure to set the property "Copy Local" of added references to True.

Answer (score 1):

Create NuGet packages for the project sources you don't want to share or have on site.

Reference those NuGet packages from projects or solutions that you're ok with having the source available.

Comment: Does this require an internet connection?

Comment: Yes, if you post your NuGet package on a publicly accessible NuGet repository (nuget.org).  But you could also stand up / install your own on-site NuGet server.